# iOS Take or Select Photo

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

The camera app on iOS allows one to take a photo, but also has the button to the left that allows one to browse the photo album.

When using the `UIImagePickerController` I can only tell them to either do one or the other.

So, rather than making a custom camera view, or even a custom overlay to add these abilities, I'll ask if there isn't some sort of flag I'm missing to allow this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When invoking it, you choose which one you want. There isn't a way to get exactly the same functionality as the camera app unless you, as you said, make a custom view for it. But wherever you want to invoke this, you could provide the options for either choosing a photo or taking one at that point.

You'll notice other apps that either let you take a photo or choose one from your library give you those as separate options within their UI.

Comment: Cool, I'm fine to have the action sheet thing that many others do, I was just making sure I couldn't ask the camera view to allow a pretaken photo. Thanks.